# PHP Undefined Index for Uploadifive formdata

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a form that after save shows the upload controls and I use 'JSON.stringify(myObject)' to generate a JSON object to pass to uploadifive so my upload.php file can create a db record, this resolves to {'record_type':'project','id':"1"}.

php is reporting an undefined index for 'record_type' and 'id', the file itself uploads successfully. how do I pass the variable to uploadifive and execute it correctly so PHP can get access to the index values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
....... //some other code
.......

   $(function(myUploadFormData){
    $('#file_input').uploadifive({                        
        'auto'              : false,
        'multi'             : false,
        'buttonClass'       : 'button',
        'formData'          : myUploadFormData,
        'buttonText'        : 'Select',
        'uploadLimit'       : 1,
        'queueID'           : 'droplist',
        'width'             : 75,
        'height'            : "25px",
        'queueSizeLimit'    : 1,
        'uploadScript'      : 'php/upload.php',
        'onUploadComplete'  : function(file, data) { console.log(data); }
     });
  });

  $("#file_upload").on("click", function() {
      $("#file_input").uploadifive('upload');
  });

});

function uploadFormData(id, record_type){
var myObject = new Object();     
myObject.record_type = record_type; 
myObject.id = id;
var myUploadFormData = JSON.stringify(myObject);
}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't expect form data to be in JSON format.

Comment: That is true but the  plugin translates the json object to a post array automatically as pper http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/formdata-2/